JNI ERROR (app bug): global reference table overflow (max=51200)global reference table dump
I'm trying to retrieve the declared methods of a class using reflection in Java, but I'm running into an error. Here’s the snippet of code I'm using:
let methods = clazz.class.getDeclaredMethods();

Essentially, I understood that it could be caused by a memory leak. By invoking the above line of code several times within a loop, over time I get the following error:
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'JNI ERROR (app bug): global reference table overflow (max=51200)global reference table dump:
  Last 10 entries (of 51200):
    51199: 0x151c6e58 java.lang.reflect.Method
    51198: 0x151c6e30 java.lang.reflect.Method
    51197: 0x151c6e08 java.lang.reflect.Method
    51196: 0x151c6de0 java.lang.reflect.Method
    [ . . . ]
        1 of java.lang.reflect.Method[] (305 elements)
        1 of java.lang.reflect.Method[] (357 elements)
        1 of java.lang.reflect.Method[] (506 elements)
        1 of dalvik.system.VMRuntime
        1 of android.app.Application
        1 of android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread
        1 of android.content.ContentProvider$Transport
        1 of android.database.ContentObserver$Transport
        1 of android.graphics.HardwareRenderer$ProcessInitializer$1
        1 of android.hardware.display.DisplayManagerGlobal$DisplayManagerCallback
        1 of android.hardware.input.InputManager$InputDevicesChangedListener
        1 of android.os.PersistableBundle$1
        1 of android.view.ViewRootImpl$W
        1 of android.view.WindowManagerGlobal$1
        1 of android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager$1
        1 of android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$1
        1 of android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ControlledInputConnectionWrapper
'
    x0  0000000000000000  x1  0000000000003a60  x2  0000000000000006  x3  000000775495b1c0
    x4  622d646c68736d74  x5  622d646c68736d74  x6  622d646c68736d74  x7  7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
    x8  00000000000000f0  x9  032d8e3d57c95433  x10 0000000000000000  x11 ffffffc0fffffbdf
    x12 0000000000000001  x13 0000000000000e11  x14 001ed617062d3e61  x15 000000000003ff50
    x16 00000079f915ac80  x17 00000079f913c870  x18 0000000000000000  x19 0000000000003a48
    x20 0000000000003a60  x21 00000000ffffffff  x22 000000000778420c  x23 000000000778420c
    x24 0000007767eac000  x25 00000077678b3017  x26 00000079fcfb686c  x27 0000007767eae000
    x28 0000007767eaf000  x29 000000775495b240
    lr  00000079f90f02a0  sp  000000775495b1a0  pc  00000079f90f02cc  pst 0000000000000000
backtrace:
      #00 pc 000000000004e2cc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so!libc.so (offset 0x4e000) (abort+164) (BuildId: 95f68a34fdf7b31f42d3f811d5d88f58)
      #01 pc 0000000000000108  <anonymous:79fe730000>
***

Just for giving you a context, I'm using Frida to orchestrate a Java application for Android. But I think that the issue is not related to Android or Frida, I think that the reflection methods are affected by memory leak. It seems that there is not a method to clean the global reference table, so in case of massive usage of the getDeclaredMethods() method, the program crashes.
Is there a Java guru here that could help me to solve this very insidious problem?
Thank you so much!
I would like to use the getDeclaredMethods as many times and to not trigger crashes related to the fact that the global offset table is not cleaned.

Could be a bug of Frida. Have you tried to do the same without reflection just using the Frida provided properties? https://github.com/frida/frida-java-bridge/issues/44#issuecomment-485746731 Anyway it would be helpful to not only have one line of Frida JS code but a whole runnable snippet that demonstrates the problem.
